# Within a bash script, can I upgrade a package, source .bash_profile, and use the updated package?

Tags: bash

On Ubuntu 9.10, I have a bash script that installs various Python libraries using `pip`. Pip is installed earlier using `apt-get install python-pip`, but this installs an old version of `pip`, and I need a newer version that supports the `--use-mirrors` option. The following commands

```
pip install --upgrade pip
source ~/.bash_profile # also tried source ~/.bashrc and source /etc/profile
pip install --use-mirrors MySQL-python
```

fail with this error when I place them in my bash script:

```
Usage: /usr/bin/pip install [OPTIONS] PACKAGE_NAMES...
/usr/bin/pip install: error: no such option: --use-mirrors
```

Can I make the `pip install --use-mirrors MySQL-python` command see and use the new version of `pip` that I'm upgrading to two lines earlier?

Edit: My .bash_profile contains:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
unset USERNAME
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `echo $PATH` and `which pip` per Ryan's advice revealed that the earlier version of pip from apt-get was getting installed in `/usr/bin`, while the upgraded pip was getting installed in `/usr/local/bin`, which was not on the PATH that was getting exported in .bash_profile or .bashrc. I needed to add `/usr/local/bin` to the PATH:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
pip install --use-mirrors MySQL-python
```

Answer (score 1):

We can't possibly tell you what that code will do unless you show us the file that you are sourcing. What are you expecting your bash_profile to do for you?

You need to figure out where the upgraded version of pip is getting installed, and what your PATH is set to before and after sourcing your bash config. Try sprinkling things like `echo $PATH` and `which pip` at strategic points throughout your script:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
echo $PATH
which pip
source ~/.bash_profile # also tried source ~/.bashrc and source /etc/profile
echo $PATH
which pip
pip install --use-mirrors MySQL-python
```

Hopefully this will give you a hint as to what is going wrong.